# junit: Tests that rely on each other

Tags: unit-testing, architecture, junit, integration-testing

I have an architectural dilemma regarding `JUnit` Test structure.

The flow of my test class test the loading of a dictionary from a large file. The class may fail due to lack of memory, file not found, wrong file structure, and so on.

On the first hand, it makes good sense to run the tests on a specific order: check for memory, then check if the file exists, then check for its structure. This would be very helpful, because if we don't have enough memory, the appropriate test would fail and give meaningful output, instead of the cryptic `OutOfMemoryException`. Moreover, I won't have to overgo the time-consuming process of reading the file over and over again.

On the other hand, tests should be isolated, self contained entities.

Any ideas how to desing the test suite?

Comment: I'm curious: what exactly is cryptic when you get an `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: a. It doesn't give you a hint about the required amount of memory needed; b. If a swap file is used, it might take ages until the exception is thrown.

Comment: Do you know the `@Before` annotation? Or alternatively `Assume.assumeTrue`?

Comment: @RolandIllig Yes. If the order of the test is not guaranteed, these are not so useful.

Comment: My idea was to make the `checkHeapMemory` a `@Before` method, since it is not really a test, but rather a prerequisite. Same for the `checkFileExists`. The question is then whether you want to silently skip the test (using `assumeTrue` in the actual test method) or if you want to fail quickly (using `@Before`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is an *integration test*, rather than a unit test. Unit tests (ideally) should not rely on the file system, amount of memory available etc.

You should set up your unit tests with a manageable amount of data in the dictionary (preferably initialized e.g. from a string (stream) within the test fixture code, not from an external file). This way you can reinitialize your test fixture independently for each unit test case, and test whatever nitty gritty details you need to about the structure of the dictionary.

And of course, you should also create separate, high level integration tests to verify that your system as a whole works as expected under real life circumstances. If these are separated from the genuine unit tests, you can afford to run the (cheap and fast) unit tests via JUnit after any code change, and run the costlier integration tests via some other way only more rarely, depending on how long they take, e.g. once every night. You may also choose between setting up the integration environment once, and running your integration tests (via some other means than JUnit, e.g. a shell / batch script) in a well defined order, or reloading the dictionary file for each test case, as the extended execution time may not matter during a nightly build.

Comment: How can I write an integration test in JUnit, in a way that respects the flow of the tests?

Comment: @AdamMatan, you can't control the order of execution of tests in JUnit. (It is fairly predictable, within the same implementation version and environment, but it may change without warning in a new version, or when run in a different environment.) I offer two alternatives in my update above.

Comment: Yes you can, just not using `@Test`; you can still create test suites with deterministic order. You *shouldn't*, almost always, but you can.

Comment: @DaveNewton, OK, fine, I implied "when using JUnit the way it is meant to be used" :-) Indeed you can execute any number of tests in a fixed order from within a single test method. Of course, that means all these tests will be seen and counted as a single test by JUnit.

Comment: Well, I meant a test suite; they're still individual tests. But I agree that in this case not the best way to handle it; order-dependent test are just evil.

Comment: JUnit is a unit testing framework, so not adequate for integration testing. TestNG (http://testng.org) support tests that depend on each other (look up the dependsOnGroups and dependsOnMethods attributes).

Comment: @CedricBeust, depends on what do you mean by "integration testing". If you mean a "fat unit test", testing a bigger component instead of a single method, why not; I prefer being pragmatic. In fact, we have loads of such tests running over JUnit in our legacy project. If you mean launching an (even tiny) app from the command line, passing a file to it and verifying its output file, this is certainly not what JUnit is meant for.

Comment: Integration testing is when you test several components together, and for this kind of testing, dependent tests are very useful and sometimes a requirement if you want to have speedy test runs and avoid having static fields everywhere in your test code base. See for example how Selenium users use TestNG with dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Péter says:

An OOME *unit* test wouldn't rely on actually running out of memory. Instead whatever calls for the file load should react appropriately when the code-that-loads throws the OOME. This is what mocking/etc. are for--simulating behavior *outside* of what is being tested. (Same for missing files/file structure errors.)

IMO loading a file that's too big for the JVM configuration isn't really a useful thing to test in the code that actually loads the file--as long as whatever calls for the file load handles an OOME appropriately--at least not in a unit test.

If the code-that-loads needs some behavior verification when the file is too big I'd consider stubbing out the file load part and *force* an OOME rather than actually load a giant file, just to save time. To reiterate his point, actual physical behavior can be moved to integration tests and, say, run on a CI server outside of your own TDD heartbeat.